# Strange compiler warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Out of nowhere I get this strange compiler warning in Xcode. This errors lead to even more errors in other files, and none of these files have been modified in days (including this one). An hour ago I was able to compile, but few minutes later I got this.

I already did a clean but that didn't help. I also retyped every special character in these files, which didn't help either.

I am using Xcode 4.6.2

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Actual source to remove downvote...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TempPartner : NSObject         //Expected identifier or '('

@property (nonatomic) NSString *key;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *fullname; //Unexpected '@' in program
@property (nonatomic) NSString *text;     //Unexpected '@' in program
@property (nonatomic) NSString *mail;     //Unexpected '@' in program

- (TempPartner *)initWithKey:(NSString *)key fullName:(NSString *)fullname text:(NSString *)text mail:(NSString *)mail;
                                          //Expected a type
                                          //Missing context for method declaration

@end                                      //Expected method body
```

Comment: Please don't show us code in screenshots please use the code snippet option and write it out. This screenshot is very hard to read. -1 for it being a screenshot, will remove when image is replaced by code.

Comment: Please verify that your `pch` file is clean of errors, especially from non-balanced brackets.

Comment: It seems like the compiler is trying to compile the file as something other than Objective-C. Check in Xcode to make sure.

Comment: You know that you can open the screenshot in a new tab to see it in the actual resolution? Posting code and every single warning that is attached is way more complicated.

Comment: I highly recommend update your xcode to 4.6.3 specially after 10.8.4 update.There are many issues happend on xcode after 10.8.4 update.

Comment: As promised I have removed my -1 for adding the code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Log Navigator (View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator). Choose your latest build. It should have a red circle next to it because of the errors. Click on it to show the log for that build. What does it say?

Check your precompiled header `.pch` file for errors, also check your AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. One of the files (which didn't even show up in the Issue Navigator) had `^^^` at the beginning.